# Save List as Strings with Java XML Annotations

Tags: java, xml, list, jaxb, flatten

I need to save some variables in a simple class using Java's XML Annotations: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html

Currently the class is pretty simple and looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Chart {

@XmlElement
public String url;
@XmlElement
public String values;
@XmlElement
public String projectOrFilterName;
@XmlElement
public String countComplains;

public Chart(String url, String values, String projectOrFilterName, String countComplains) {
    this.url = url;
    this.values = values;
    this.projectOrFilterName = projectOrFilterName;
    this.countComplains = countComplains;
}
}
```

Now I need to save the data of a list as string variables with annotations like the existing ones. Im giving the constructor some kind of a list, let's say

```
List<Object>
```

The question is, how to extract all the variables out of it, and save their toString() representations with the given XML Annotations. If that's simpler one could assume, I get a List of Strings.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate or give example of what out put you want.

Comment: I want to pass a List to the Chart constructor. Let it be a List<String> object. Then I want to take the elements in the List and save them as members with XML Annotations like I've done with the other three strings in my example. Perhaps there is a way to directly save the list as a member and, easily said, annotate it somehow, so it's like a node for the list and child nodes for each element.

Comment: In this particular example I'd like to save the chart's data points in addtition to it's url and so on. It doesn't have anything to do with Chart.toString(). I'm sorry for the missunderstanding.

Comment: I think I finally found something: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlList.html   I try to use this, according to the given example.

Comment: The following may help:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who could have known, it would be that simple ;-)

```
@XmlElement
public List<String> data;
```

That's just, what I needed. The java script part, interpreting the xml creates an array out of the list's elements and everything is fine.
Thanks for your time thinking over my question!